# Condition fails in react native production, but works in development

Tags: javascript, date, react-native

I have created a react native app, by which I need compare from and to date. And if it's true, execution will be done.

The problem is, the condition works in react native development mode and not working in react native production release. I am using firebase for the database, also using redux.

Here is my code:

```
  var d = new Date();
  const fromDate = extract.validFrom.split("-").reverse(); //"01-02-2019"
  const tillDate = extract.validTill.split("-").reverse(); //"10-03-2019"
  var k = new Date(fromDate)
  var j = new Date(tillDate)
```

The condition need to verified is :

```
if(d.getDate() >= k.getDate() === true && d.getDate() <= j.getDate() === true){...some code}else{this.props.error("Code Expired")}
```

This works, absolutely fine while in development, but the condition is failing and moving to else. I don't know why. The form and till date is retired from firebase.

Please help me to solve.

Comment: can try simplifying the condition to `if(d.getDate() >= k.getDate() && d.getDate() <= j.getDate()){...some code}else{this.props.error("Code Expired")}`

Comment: What difference it would make ?

Comment: what is the value variable `d` in production?

Comment: are you comparing date or time because `date.getDate()` and `d.getTime()`  are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this, happens because of different javascript core. As , chrome has latest version of core, but react native doesnt. So you need to give date as per ES6, change the date "01-02-2019" to

```
"Fri Feb 02 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)".
```

And after that, remove

```
.split("-").reverse(); on both dates.
```

Hope Fully it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Once I come across the same issue with date. Then I have tried to enclose the value with `new Date()` and that helped me. I thought your problem is also similar to that. Try to compare as

```
if((new Date(d) >= new Date(k)) && (new Date(d) <= new Date(j))){
   ...some code
}
```