# Firestore - function works in development mode but does not work in production

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to figure out how to setup a react firebase web app.

I have a firebase.js config file with all of the methods below. The helper that runs the register method is included in this file as:

```
async register({email, password, name, beta, roleNominated}) {
          await this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
          await this.auth.currentUser.updateProfile({
            displayName: name,
          })
          const uid = this.auth.currentUser.uid;
          await 
            this.firestore.collection("users").doc(uid).set({ 
            role: 'PENDING',
            createdAt: app.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
```

The whole file is:

```
import app from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';
// import 'firebase/storage';


const devConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_APP_ID

};


const prodConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_PROD_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_PROD_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_PROD_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROD_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_PROD_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROD_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROD_APP_ID
};


const config =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? prodConfig : devConfig;





class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(config)
    this.firestore = app.firestore();
    this.auth = app.auth();

  }

  // helper functions for authentication and user management
  async register({email, password, name, beta, roleNominated}) {
      await this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      await this.auth.currentUser.updateProfile({
        displayName: name,
      })
      const uid = this.auth.currentUser.uid;
      await 
        this.firestore.collection("users").doc(uid).set({ 
        role: 'PENDING',
        createdAt: app.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      });
      await this.auth.currentUser.sendEmailVerification();
  }

  login(email, password) {
    return this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  };

  logout() {
    return this.auth.signOut();
  }

  getUser() {
    return  this.auth.currentUser();
  }

  authChange(user) {
      return this.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user);
  }

  sendEmailVerification = () =>
      this.getUser.sendEmailVerification({
      // url: process.env.REACT_APP_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL_REDIRECT
      url: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? process.env.REACT_APP_PROD_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL_REDIRECT : process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL_REDIRECT,
    });

};

export default new Firebase();
```

I have a signup form with:

```
import import Firebase from '../../../../firebase.js';
```

then, register is called in the onCreate:

```
const onCreate = async values => {
    try {
        await Firebase.register(values)
    } catch(err){
        console.error(err);
    }    
    setVisible(false);
  };
```

register is imported from the firebase.js file.

When I run this in my local environment - I successfully authenticate a user in the firebase auth module and create a user document in the users collection with the values I've asked for in the register method.

When I deploy this to the production environment, the auth step succeeds but errors are generated when it tries to make a document in the users collection. The error message says:

> TypeError: this.firestore.collection(...).set is not a function

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54998402/condition-fails-in-react-native-production-but-works-in-development) which also has a problem deploying code that works in development, but fails in firebase production. That particular issue seems to be related to how dates are used in ES6.

I have the same security rules in both production and development projects and both have:

```
match /users/{userId} {
      allow read;
      allow write;
    }
```

Is there any advice for how to figure out what is preventing the firestore user collection from creating a document in the production environment?

Comment: This has nothing to do with security rules.  Where is the line of code that fails using `this.firestore`?  I don't see it here.

Comment: Its in the register method in firebase.js: await 
        this.firestore.collection("users").doc(uid).set({ 
        role: 'PENDING',
        createdAt: app.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      });

Comment: Would you like to edit the question to include these details, to be clear what all is going on here?  It's always good to show the actual code that's failing, in the context where it fails.

Comment: It's copied from firebase.js in a separate block in the amended post above. Thanks for having a look.